# Exhausetd ResultSet Error when fetching from a perticular column

Tags: exception, servlets, servletexception, ojdbc

In my project, I am creating a **Cancel Account** facility to delete the account from user table. The user table name is `newuser`. The `cancelaccount` jsp looks like:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
   <style type="text/css">
body {
background-image: url("shocked.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: top right;
 }
p
 {
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
    size: 5px;
    text-align: center;
 }

 </style>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <form action="Cancelaccount" name="cancelaccount">
 <p>Are you sure to cancel account?</p>
 <p>If yes please retype the password</p>
 <p><input type="password" align="middle" name="password"></input></p>
 <input type="submit" value="Cancel Account"></input>
 <p>Else click <a href="UserHome.jsp">here</a></p> 
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

In `Cancelaccount` servlet, I am trying to match the current input password with the password registered with the account open. If they match the account should be cancelled,otherwise not.So the servlet code is:

```
import getset.Getset;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import accessdb.Dao;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class Cancelaccount extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
                                                              IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Getset g = new Getset();
        Dao dao = new Dao();
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String userid = (String)session.getAttribute("userid");
        if (password.equals("") || password.equals(" "))
            response.sendRedirect("UserHome.jsp");
        g.setuserid(userid);
        g.setloginpassword(password);
        try {
            String password1 = dao.getregpasswordbyuserid(g);
            if (password1 == password) {
                dao.cancelaccount(g);
                pw.println("<html>Your Account has been successfully cancelled from the system.<p>" +
                           "Click here to go to <a href=\"WelcomePage.jsp\">Start Page</a><html>");
                session.invalidate();

            } else {
                response.sendRedirect("UserHome.jsp");
            }


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The `DAO` functions code are:

```
public void cancelaccount(Getset g)throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException{
    //Delete a user from NEWUSER TABLE AND MEALDB TABLE
    Connection con=Dbconnection.getConnection();
    String userid=g.getuserid();
    PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("delete from mealdb where userid=?");
    pstmt.setString(1, userid);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
    PreparedStatement pstmt1=con.prepareStatement("delete from newuser where userid=?");
    pstmt1.setString(1, userid);
    pstmt1.executeUpdate();
}
public String getregpasswordbyuserid(Getset g)throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException{
    //GET PASSWORD BY USERID
    Connection con=Dbconnection.getConnection();
    String userid=g.getuserid();
    PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("select regpassword from newuser where userid=?");
    pstmt.setString(1, userid);
    ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    String p=rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println(""+p);
    return p;

}
```

And the `stacktrace` is:

```
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR] java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:125)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:162)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:227)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getString(OracleResultSetImpl.java:347)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at accessdb.Dao.getregpasswordbyuserid(Dao.java:245)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at Cancelaccount.doGet(Cancelaccount.java:39)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
     11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:580) 
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    11:35:29,912 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In the `DAO`s' `cancelaccount` function I deleted from another table `mealdb` also, because the `userid` field is a `primary key` in `newuser` and `foreign key` in `mealdb`. I looked into it hard, but could not find a way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved. I just changed the servlet code and it worked. The **userid** value from the session was not being fetched successfully. The working code is:

```
import getset.Getset;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import accessdb.Dao;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class Cancelaccount extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
                                                              IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Getset g = new Getset();
        Dao dao = new Dao();
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        System.out.println("" + password);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String userid = (String)session.getAttribute("USERID");
        System.out.println("" + userid);
        /*  if(password.equals("") || password.equals(" "))
    {
    response.sendRedirect("UserHome.jsp");

    } */
        g.setuserid(userid);
        try {
            String password1 = dao.getpasswordbyuserid(g);
            System.out.println("" + password1);
            if (password1.equals(password)) {
                dao.cancelaccount(g);
                pw.println("<html>Your Account has been successfully cancelled from the system.<p>" +
                           "Click here to go to <a href=\"WelcomePage.jsp\">Start Page</a><html>");
                session.invalidate();

            } else {
                response.sendRedirect("UserHome.jsp");
            }


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: And Thanks @MaVRoSCy  for your unquestionable cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the code in the  getregpasswordbyuserid() to

```
ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
String p="";
while(rs.next()){
    p=rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println(""+p);
}
return p;
```

Comment: Sorry, did not make it running!!

Comment: PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("delete from mealdb where userid=?",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
 ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATEABLE);

Comment: use it also in the getregpasswordbyuserid(), there is your problem comming from i think

Comment: Tried everywhere,but of no use!! :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14507/discussion-between-mavroscy-and-subir-adhikari)